# Cassandra role/user that only logins and "see" a specific keyspace/table

Tags: cassandra, devops

I want to configure a cassandra role/user that only logins and "see" a specific keyspace/table.

Here is my test setup:

```
1. CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_test WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};
2. CREATE ROLE role_test WITH PASSWORD = 'role_test$pw' AND LOGIN = true;
3. GRANT ALL PERMISSIONS ON KEYSPACE keyspace_test to role_test;
```

Now, my role "role_test" just can query the keypace "keyspace_test" and can't query other keyspaces, which is ok, but "role_test" can LOGIN into and DESCRIBE other keyspaces, despite it can't do nothing I really want to prevent this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cassandra documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/security.html#revoke-permission-statement) on revoking permissions, certain tables "cannot have their `SELECT` permissions revoked".  These tables are:

```
* `system_schema.keyspaces`
* `system_schema.columns`
* `system_schema.tables`
* `system.local`
* `system.peers`
```

A `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE` command will retrieve information from `system_schema.keyspaces`, therefore that command will be available to any authorized user.